# Query DSL terms filtering with script for day by numeric value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Within aggs I am able to get buckets by day of the week that are represented in numeric (1-7) keys using something like this:

```
"aggs" : {
      "group_by_day" :{
        "terms": {
          "script": "doc['@timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek",
            "order": {
                "_key": "asc"
            }
        }
      }
  }
```

however I am looking for a way to add to the query filtering terms clause something like this to only show results for a monday or tuesday and haven't been able to get this:

I have tried

```
    {
      "terms": {
          "script":"doc['@timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek"
      }
    }
```

and the use of script tag doesn't seem to be supported in terms query? at least how I am attempting to use it. Is there another way to get at filtering with script, or another approach (better) to get want I am trying to achieve? I am using 6.2...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is it:

```
"script":{
   "script": {
       "source": "doc['@timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek == 1"
    }
}
```

Where I just handle the string to numeric conversion outside of this query, this is within a query.bool.must clause.